# What happens to in-flight webjobs transactions when new function code is deployed?

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Event Hub trigger function which consumes a consistent volume of events 24/7 and appends data to blob.

I'd like to know how the function handles in-flight events when new code is deployed to the function app?

I assume that the trigger is paused but what happens to events that have been consumed and are in the process of being written to blob? Does the function wait for these transactions to be completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function host process would be restarted during the deployment or file change event. Let's say the function is processing an event "e1" and deployment has started, the host will make sure that the event e1 is processed and then the host is restarted so that the new code is deployed. The pending events (e2,e3 etc) would be processed by the new code. As you mentioned, the function host will wait for the ongoing transactions to be completed.